Why did scholars say that doing the taslim with the imam is makrooh when the sahaba did it themselves?
As-salamu alaykum wa Rahmatullahi wa barakatoh. I came across a hadith which goes like this:

Sahih al-Bukhari 838 Narrated `Itban bin Malik:
We prayed with the Prophet (ﷺ) and used to finish our prayer with the
Taslim along with him.

And many people use this hadith as a evidence that doing the taslim with the imam is allowed and sunnah. Now my question is, how come scholars like Ibn Uthaymeen RH and others say that it is makrooh to say the taslim along with the imam when the companions did it themselves?
Source:

Al-Nawawi (may Allah have mercy on him) said in al-Majmoo’ (3/464):
Al-Baghawi said: It is mustahabb not to start the salaam until the
imam has finished both taslims. This is the view of al-Shaafa’i
according to al-Buwayti, as was quoted by al-Baghawi. He said: Whoever
is (praying) behind an imam, when the imam has finished his salaam, he
should say salaam to his right and his left. End quote.
Shaykh Ibn ‘Uthaymeen (may Allah have mercy on him) said in al-Sharh
al-Mumti’ (4/267): The scholars said: It is makrooh to say the first
and second taslim with your imam, but if you say the first taslim
after his first taslim and the second taslim after his second taslim,
there is nothing wrong with that, but it is better not to say the
taslim until after he has said both taslims. End quote.

So how came those Great scholars say that it is mustahab not to say the taslim with the imam, and that it is makrooh when it was a practice by the sahaba?
JazakAllahu Khayran.

It should be considered that 'Itban ibn Malik became blind after the battle of Al-Khandaq and that scholarly views are ijtihad.

The hadith does not clearly state that they did it simultaneously with the Prophet ﵆, rather it may mean that they did it immediately after the Prophet ﵆ and did not delay or continue with their prayer. The general rule is that the Imam is to be followed, first the Imam does an act and then you do it, doing something before or simultaneously with him is not truly following him.

‏ إنما جعل الإمام ليؤتم به فإذا ركع فاركعوا وإذا رفع فارفعوا
The Imam is appointed to be followed, so when he bows, then bow, and when he stands up, then stand up
— Nasai

The exact method, i.e. whether to start after the Imam finishes, or to start immediately after the Imam starts but before he finishes etc. is a matter of ijtihad.
Ref: Fath al-Bari
